# Taking Element in matrix with Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

```
import numpy as np

m = np.matrix('[1, 2; 3, 4]')
print(m[0][0])
```

I expected to see `1`.
But it shows me `[[1 2]]`.
How can I get `1` instead?

Comment: The use of `np.matrix` is [not recommended](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) anymore. prefer `m = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tranbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13525512/tranbi) mentioned, the `np.matrix` official documentation states:

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear
> algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the
> future.

If you still wish to use `np.matrix`, it supports the [np.matrix.item()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.item.html) method, and you can get the first element by:

```
m.item((0, 0))
```

or

```
m.item(0)
```

which will yield:

```
1
```

If you do follow the recommendation of switching to [np.array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html),

```
m = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
m[0][0]
```

would yield `1`

Comment: Thank you! I hope to know there is transpose or other linear operator for  'array'.

Comment: @PathInt. since `np.array` is of type `ndarray`, it supports transpose (by typing `m.T` for example) and many other attributes and methods which can be found [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)

oh and if you can, accept this answer by ticking the V at it's left side :)